# UPDATE table. SET statement wrong syntax?

Tags: mysql, sql

I need some more help. OK, I've got a table as follows:

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM MODELOS;
+--------+----------+---------+
| ID_MOD | ID_MARCA | MODELO  |
+--------+----------+---------+
|      1 |     NULL | PICASSA |
|      2 |     NULL | C4      |
|      3 |     NULL | C3      |
|      4 |     NULL | C2      |
|      5 |     NULL | MONDEO  |
|      6 |     NULL | S-MAX   |
|      7 |     NULL | CIVIC   |
|      8 |     NULL | ACCORD  |
|      9 |     NULL | CLS     |
|     10 |     NULL | 900     |
|     11 |     NULL | LEON    |
|     12 |     NULL | IBIZA   |
|     13 |     NULL | 307     |
|     14 |     NULL | 308     |
|     15 |     NULL | 407     |
|     16 |     NULL | 408     |
|     17 |     NULL | MEGANE  |
|     18 |     NULL | PASSAT  |
|     19 |     NULL | GOLF    |
|     20 |     NULL | TOUAREG |
+--------+----------+---------+
```

and another one, FILE, which looks like this:

```
+----------+------------+---------+-----------+--------+
| ID_MARCA | MARCA      | MODELO  | MATRICULA | PRECIO |
+----------+------------+---------+-----------+--------+
|        1 | CITROEN    | PICASSA | CPG-2044  |  12000 |
|        1 | CITROEN    | PICASSA | CPR-1762  |  12500 |
|        1 | CITROEN    | C4      | FPP-1464  |  13500 |
|        1 | CITROEN    | C4      | FDR-4563  |  13000 |
|        1 | CITROEN    | C3      | BDF-8856  |   8000 |
|        1 | CITROEN    | C3      | BPZ-7878  |   7500 |
|        1 | CITROEN    | C2      | CDR-1515  |   5000 |
|        1 | CITROEN    | C2      | BCC-3434  |   4500 |
|        2 | FORD       | MONDEO  | BTG-3267  |   8000 |
|        2 | FORD       | MONDEO  | BPP-6792  |   8200 |
|        2 | FORD       | S-MAX   | FDR-1564  |  20000 |
|        2 | FORD       | S-MAX   | FCE-9327  |  21000 |
|        3 | HONDA      | CIVIC   | FCC-7764  |  16000 |
|        3 | HONDA      | CIVIC   | FBC-4567  |  14000 |
|        3 | HONDA      | ACCORD  | FFC-6768  |  22000 |
|        3 | HONDA      | ACCORD  | FPB-2231  |  23000 |
|        4 | MERCEDES   | CLS     | FDR-2265  |  31000 |
|        5 | SAAB       | 900     | FPG-1165  |  21000 |
|        6 | SEAT       | LEON    | DVB-1119  |  14500 |
|        6 | SEAT       | LEON    | DCR-5634  |  13500 |
|        6 | SEAT       | IBIZA   | DPR-3434  |   9500 |
|        6 | SEAT       | IBIZA   | DPP-8756  |  10000 |
|        7 | PEUGEOT    | 307     | DGX-4598  |   5500 |
|        7 | PEUGEOT    | 307     | DGG-2098  |   5000 |
|        7 | PEUGEOT    | 308     | DPK-3859  |   5500 |
|        7 | PEUGEOT    | 308     | DVK-4987  |   6000 |
|        7 | PEUGEOT    | 407     | FFK-1513  |   7500 |
|        7 | PEUGEOT    | 407     | FPP-3768  |   8000 |
|        7 | PEUGEOT    | 408     | CPG-7879  |  10000 |
|        7 | PEUGEOT    | 408     | CRC-9738  |   9500 |
|        8 | RENAULT    | MEGANE  | CQC-4298  |  11000 |
|        8 | RENAULT    | MEGANE  | FNZ-7688  |   6000 |
|        9 | VOLKSWAGEN | PASSAT  | FNR-3987  |  16000 |
|        9 | VOLKSWAGEN | PASSAT  | FQK-3987  |  18000 |
|        9 | VOLKSWAGEN | GOLF    | FCJ-0909  |  22500 |
|        9 | VOLKSWAGEN | GOLF    | FCK-3989  |  21000 |
|        9 | VOLKSWAGEN | TOUAREG | DGG-0937  |  42000 |
+----------+------------+---------+-----------+--------+
```

What I am trying to do is to update column ID_MARCA in table MODELOS in a way that ID_MARCA corresponds with field in column MODELO. For example, in table MODELOS I have a field PICASSA, and I need corresponding field in column ID_MARCA to be of value 1 as it is ID of CITROEN and PICASSA, if you look into a table FILE is a CITROEN.
So, I've got this update statement:

```
UPDATE TABLE MODELOS
 SET ID_MARCA = (SELECT ID_MARCA FROM FILE)
 WHERE FILE.MARCA IN (SELECT MARCA FFROM MODELOS);
```

but this statement returns SQL syntax error.

Comment: You can't set a field to the result set of another query.  You need to join

Comment: Edited to remove the SQL Server tag since it is obviously MySQL

Comment: `FFROM` -> `FROM`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, note that there are multiple rows for a given file with a given `marca`.  You probably don't want to do multiple updates.

Second, I don't readily detect a *syntax* error in your query.  I do detect two runtime errors.  The first is that (in MySQL) you can't reference the table being updated (this might be a compile-time error).  Second, your subqueries are returning multiple rows.

If you want to follow your path of using a subquery, then use a correlated subquery:

```
UPDATE MODELOS m
  SET m.ID_MARCA = (SELECT f.ID_MARCA
                    FROM FILE f
                    WHERE f.MARCA = m.MARCA
                    LIMIT 1
                   );
```

Comment: It still gives me an error though: ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'table MODELOS m set m.ID_MARCA = (select f.ID_MARCA from FILE f where f.MARCA = ' at line 1   Same as before.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend you don't use subqueries for update, if for any reason than ma of MySQL up through 5.7 cannot optimize inside a subquery.

From the docs: (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/subquery-optimization.html)

> **Note**
>
> A limitation on UPDATE and DELETE statements that use a subquery to modify a single table is that the optimizer does not use semi-join or materialization subquery optimizations. As a workaround, try rewriting them as multiple-table UPDATE and DELETE statements that use a join rather than a subquery.

I'd use a join join:

```
UPDATE TABLE MODELOS m
  JOIN FILE f ON m.MARCA = f.MARCA
  SET m.ID_MARCA = f.ID_MARCA
```

Comment: . . Of course you can set a field to the result of a subquery.  That statement is just patently false.

Comment: @GordonLinoff  indeed you are correct.  I've now changed my answer to I don't recommend using subqueries for updates

Answer (score 0):

When you are updating form another table always use MERGE function which is very much efficient.

```
MERGE INTO MODELOS M
  USING FILE F
    ON (M.MODELO = F.MODELO)
    WHEN MATCHED THEN
    UPDATE SET
M.ID_MARCA = F.ID_MARCA;
```

Answer (score 0):

OK, I got a solution for it. Got rid of all data in table MODELOS and updated it using table FILE in a following manner:

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO TABLE MODELOS (ID_MARCA, MODELO)
-> SELECT ID_MODELO, MODELO 
-> FROM FILE;
```

Apparently best solutions are simple solutions. Thank you everyone for your help and suggestions. Much appreaciated.